# Why does my on click button not work. JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

just wondering if anyone can quickly point out in my JSfiddle link below why this on click isn't working.

Wrecking my head, I've tried multiple different event binding techniques but can't seme to get it to work.

Html:

```
    <form method="GET">
    <input type="button" id="inject_XML_details" value="Show Details" />
    </form>
    <div id="xml_details">asd</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function loadTemp(){
 $("#xml_details").append("<p class='myBold'>" + "LOLOLOLOL" + "</p>");
 });
        $("#inject_XML_details").on("click",function(){
            $("#xml_details").empty();
            loadTemp();       
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nLRvH/17/
Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/nLRvH/19/

Comment: My chrome says nothing, just >

Comment: A regular function is closed with just `}`, not `});`, and my Chrome shows errors

Comment: Also, case matter, the selector and the ID doesn't match

Comment: @user1839601 also my chrome didnt say anything.But it showed me errors

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

you have an extra `)` after `function loadTemp(){    });` and you're calling `#inject_XML_details` and it's `#inject_xml_details`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is $ function is case sensitive so that is not the same $('A') than $('a').

Better example:

```
$("#inject_xml_details") and $("#inject_XML_details") are different.
```

It is working now, please take a look:

http://jsfiddle.net/SabdielRivera/nLRvH/23/

Answer (score 0):

You have got unnecessary bracket after function loadTemp.

```
 function loadTemp(){
     $("#xml_details").append("<p class='myBold'>" + "LOLOLOLOL" + "</p>");
 }
```

instead of

```
(...)
});
```

And as @jmore009 pointed, selectors are case sensitive - in selectors you have got `inject_xml_details`, in JS - `inject_XML_details`

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure, but your page reloads on click of the button?
in that case:

```
$("#inject_XML_details").on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        $("#xml_details").empty();
        loadTemp();       
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your id has capitalization, they don't match. Here is a working fiddle [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nLRvH/22/). I changed the underscores to hyphens, just while testing, but your issue is because the id's didn't match. I also removed the unnecessary bracket.

You target `#inject_XML_details`, in the HTML the id is `inject_xml_details` xml with lowercase.

```
function loadTemp() {
    $("#xml-details").append("<p class='myBold'>" + "LOLOLOLOL" + "</p>");
};
$("#inject-xml-details").on("click", function () {
    $("#xml-details").empty();
    loadTemp();
});
```